# Why is there a different new step to implement Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I have seen that one step has changed in one step of the **build.gradle at project level**

A month ago:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
// Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
google() // Google's Maven repository
}
dependencies {

// Add this line
classpath 'com.google.gms:qoogle-services:4.3.3'
}
}

allprojects {

repositories{
// Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
google() // Google's Maven repository

}
}
```

Now:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
  // ...

  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

My question is, is it totally fine to continue using the old step? It is apparently working and I don't have even `id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false` at plugins of the build.gradle...

Why this step has changed? I would like what is the difference of this new step